# Filter != NULL in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I have the following Query in GraphDB 9.4. As shown in the results includes "NULL"^^xsd:datetime. I use filter as shown in the comment to only select valid data. When I do so, I get no results (No data available in table). Even any other filter content will result in no results. Is there any other adjustment for the Filter necessary?

```
select Distinct ?PDID ?MAT ?PStart ?DT ?Duration where { 
    
    ?PDID :DP1 ?PStart.
    ?PDID :OP1 ?PN.
    ?MAT :OP2 ?PN.
    ?MAT :DP2 ?DT.
  #  Filter (?PStart !=  "NULL") 
  # bind (ofn:hoursBetween(?PStart, ?DT) as ?Duration)    
}
```

Results

[image: Results]

Comment: I don't see why the filter should lead to an empty result. Clearly, the filter won't exclude the result as you hope, but it should just return all rows as before.

Comment: regarding the correct filter, the datatype is missing to get it working. And you should apply it to `?DT.` according to your shown results

Comment: Indeed - it should be ?DT  filter for my use case. I wanted to see if also ?PStart filtering will be without any result. I get no data filtering any of the variables. Also try xsd:datetime "NULL". But I got really confused because any filter leads to no results.

Comment: Your hint datatype-hint is completly right. The data is casted as date!

Comment: `Filter (?DT !=  "NULL"^^xsd:date)` should work. I don't understand why you're getting an empty resultset, this would only happen if the filter always evaluates to `false`. By the way, casting of `?DT`, i.e. `xsd:date(?DT)` should fail as it's an invalid literal. Without taking the datatype into account, you have to get the lexical form, i.e. `Filter (str(?DT) !=  "NULL")`

Comment: `Filter (str(?DT) !=  "NULL")` works. For `Filter (?DT !=  "NULL"^^xsd:date)` returns: Query evaluation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NULL (HTTP status 500)

Comment: can you show the stack trace? But it looks like the query is parsed and this fails because of an illegal value for `xsd:date` datatype.

Comment: Comparing literals with incompatible datatypes is non-deterministic and cause the evaluation of `FILTER` to be always `false` thus, for all solutions when `?DT` is bound to a literal with `xsd:dateTime` the filter is evaluated to false and when ?DT is bound to `"NULL"^^xsd:Date` the result is correctly set to false. One way to workaround is to use `FILTER (!sameTerm(?DT, "NULL"^^xsd:date))`